# React: onSubmit for embedded form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, cognitoforms

I have a react application with an embedded form from [cognito forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/62/data-integration/client-side-events). The script I have below embeds the form in my component. However, I want to add an `onSubmit` function within the component for that form. I tried to simply add `onSubmit` to the `iframe` but that does not do anything.

According to their docs, you are supposed to add a `script`:

```
<script>
  Cognito.on('beforeSubmit', function(event) {
    if (event.data.entry.Name.First === 'Bob')
      event.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

But I have no idea how to implement that in React. I get the error `'Cognito.on' is not a function`. Here is the code I have embedding the form:

```
{indJob &&
    <iframe src={indJob.forms.electrical}></iframe>
    <script src="https://www.cognitoforms.com/f/iframe.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: Iframe has it's own separate context and browser doesn't allow parent application and Iframe to share stuff directly. So in your case try rendering the `cognitoform's` script inside your Iframe source code on top level.